# What Script I can use to install powershell on any machine?

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

What Script I can use to install powershell on any machine?
as I have some xp machine in network and wants to install remotely on those machine,

windows 7 , its by default

Also, how could I run any script remotely on any machine in network?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSUS or SCCM, you can (and should) push it out via those mechanisms. Otherwise, you will have to install it the same way you install any other Windows Update or software.

Be advised that PowerShell 2.0 requires XP SP3, and PowerShell 3.0 will not install on XP at all.